# How should I change the permissions PRIVATEMSG for users in order them to have the access?

Tags: users, privatemsg

Good day,
I've marked read, write and delete the privatemsg for the authenticated users but they don't still have access to the pages such as user/user-id/messages. The access is only granted with "read all" permission.
I use privatemsg 6.x-1.5
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The normal user interface is at /messages, user/uid/messages is only meant to read messages of other users and is not a full replacement.

6.x-2.x has a feature that allows to move it around but it's relatively complex and I wouldn't necessarly recommend using.